# Find the largest segment

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have seven lines with different measures. The length of each line it's a positive integer and the shortest length is equal to 1 cm. It is known that's impossible to choose three of them that makes a triangle.

What is the minimum possible length for the largest line?

I only know that the sum of any three segments should not be divisible by three.

Comment: Is the fact that the sum of any three segments is not divisible by three a conjecture or a part of the problem statement?  If it is a part of the problem statement, then why did you state it *after* the question?  My thoughts on the problem: If you cannot make a triangle with the lines, then they fail the **triangle inequality** ($x+y\geq z$), so in particular, with the lengths in increasing order you have each number is larger than the sum of the previous two:  E.g. $1,2,4,7,12,20,...$.

Comment: If you require that among these seven lengths, no sum of three of the lengths is divisible by three, that is not possible by pigeon-hole principle.  Partitioning the segments into classes based on what the remainder is when dividing by three, you see that there is one partition with at least three members in the same class.  When adding those together, it will necessarily be a multiple of three.

Comment: @JMoravitz, It is not part of the statement, it's my personal opinion. Am I wrong?

Comment: yes, as shown by my second comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you say that a line is not a triangle, then simply follow the fibbonacci numbers: 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13 (formed by adding the two preceding numbers - note that the smallest number is equal to the 'second smallest' number). You can see from this series that for a number $n$, the possible values to try to use to make a triangle are either $n$ and (($n-1$ and $n-2$) or ($n-1$ and $n+1$) or ($n+1$ and $n+2$))  but these choices of numbers will give straight lines. Since any other choice of numbers would result in the ends of the points not being able to touch, no triangles can be formed. Thus, the eighth number in the list is the largest length.